# How to pass arguments automatically in LiveScript

Tags: partial-application, livescript

How I can simplify line 3 (onChange property):

```
Input do
  name: \input
  onChange: (event, value) ~> @limitInput { type: \string }, event, value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a bound partial application, [documented here](http://livescript.net/#functions). Example:

```
Input do
  name: \input
  onChange: @~limitInput({type: \string}, _, _)
```